# Get a subset of lines from a big text file using PowerShell v2

Tags: powershell, text-files

I'm working with a big text file, I mean more than 100 MB big, and I need to loop through a specific number of lines, a kind of subset so I'm trying with this,

```
$info = Get-Content -Path $TextFile | Select-Object -Index $from,$to
foreach ($line in $info)
{
,,,
```

But it does not work. It is like if it only gets the first line in the subset.

I don't find documentation about the Index attribute, so is this possible or should I try using a different approach considering the file size?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
PS> help select -param index

-Index <Int32[]>
    Selects objects from an array based on their index values. Enter the indexes in a comma-separated list.

    Indexes in an array begin with 0, where 0 represents the first value and (n-1) represents the last value.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Based on the above, '8,13' will get you just two lines. One thing you can do is pass an array of numbers, you can use the range operator:

```
Get-Content -Path $TextFile | Select-Object -Index (8..13) | Foreach-Object {...}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are the rows of fixed length? If they are, you can seek to desired position by simply calculating `offset*row length` and using something like .Net `FileStream.Seek()`. If they are not, all you can do is to read file row by row.

To extract lines m, n, try something like

```
# Open text file
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText($myFile)
$i=0
# Read lines until there are no lines left. Count the lines too
while( ($l = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    # If current line is within extract range, print it
    if($i -ge $m -and $i -le $n) {
        $("Row {0}: {1}" -f $i, $l)
    }
    $i++
    if($i -gt $n) { break } # Stop processing the file when row $n is reached.
}
# Close the text file reader
$reader.Close()
$reader.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

The below is working for me.
It extract all the content between 2 lines.

```
$name     = "MDSinfo"
$MDSinfo  = "$PSScriptRoot\$name.txt" #create text file
$MDSinfo  = gc $MDSinfo

$from =  ($MDSinfo | Select-String -pattern "sh feature" | Select-Object LineNumber).LineNumber
$to =  ($MDSinfo  | Select-String -pattern "sh flogi database " | Select-Object LineNumber).LineNumber

$i = 0
$array = @()
foreach ($line in $MDSinfo)
{
foreach-object { $i++ }
    if (($i -gt $from) -and ($i -lt $to))
    {
    $array += $line      
    }
}
$array
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Select-String $FilePath -pattern "FromHere" | Out-Null

$FromHereStartingLine = Select-String $FilePath -pattern "FromHere" | Select-Object LineNumber

$UptoHereStartingLine = Select-String $FilePath -pattern "UptoHere" | Select-Object LineNumber

for($i=$FromHereStartingLine.LineNumber; $i -lt $UptoHereStartingLine.LineNumber; $i+=1)
{
    $HoldInVariable += Get-Content -Path $FilePath | Foreach-Object { ($_  -replace "`r*`n*","") } | Select-Object -Index $i
}

Write-Host "HoldInVariable : " $HoldInVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

The Get-Content cmdlet has a readcount and totalcount parameters. I would play around with those and try to set it up so that the lines your interested in get assigned to an object, then use that object for your loops.