# Remove and add words in .csv file

Tags: c#, csv, ssis

please,I have a `.csv` file this file look like that

```
 Example Company                        
(999) 999-9999                      
 http://yourwebsite.com                             
 Report Date Range: Dec 26, 2013 - Dec 26, 2013                     
 Exported: Dec 26, 2013                             
 Twitter : Profile Summary                              
Screen Name,Name,Description,Location,Followers,Following,Listed

SctaSa,statisticalgraph,statistical Screen- The official account for your organization,Saudi Arabia,6775,8,75
```

So, I need to take specific data from the `.csv` file to be readable to SSIS Transformation, start from column "Screen Name" and add two columns "Report Date Range"& "Exported" which existing in the row number 4&5 to put them in the end of column list after that put the data of these two columns in the end of data rows and remove the garbage data,to be look like that

```
Screen Name,Name,Description,Location,Followers,Following,Listed,Exported,Report Date Range
SctaSa,statisticalgraph,statistical Screen- The official account for your organization,Saudi Arabia,6775,8,75,26-Dec-13,26-Dec-13
```

Can we do that by Windows command or C#?

please, help because i'm not expert in C# and i want to use this script in SSIS project

Thanks for help

Comment: Do the headings ("example company to screen name,..) occur only once in the file? if so, you can probably do all the work in SSIS

Comment: How I can do it in SSIS ?! give me head lines about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with C# then I suggest you [use PowerShell](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/216d2ee6-0f04-480f-808d-8241bc4a8d18/execute-powershell-script-from-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices) or similar to do this instead. That'll be much easier to test on the command line and modify going forward.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14353603/8479) for how to get specific lines from a text file using PowerShell.

Then either user PowerShell to add the additional text, or probably better would be to use SSIS to add new columns and provide values, that way you minimise the amount of text manipulation. And presumably the data values come from somewhere that will be easier to get from SSIS than in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Something on these lines to do it in SSIS (I'm sure it can be improved):

Data flow:

- Source Component: 
  read the csv , delimited by CRLF (i.e. each row is will return one column to the pipeline)
- Derived column: 
  split by token “:” when you find substring “ Exported” or “Report Date Range”
- Script component:
  Save derived columns to Exported  / Report Date Range to variables
- Conditional split: isHeading(column==”ScreenName,Name,Description,Location,Followers,Following,Listed”)
  isDetailLine 
  (token “,”  appears x number of  times)
- Derived column If  isHeading :
  Pipeline column  + “,Exported, Report Date Range”
- Derived column If  isDetailLine:
  Pipeline column  + “,” + variable Exported +”,” + variable Report  Date Range
- Union
- Destination Component